# Webview loadUrl() from file on local storage (not assets)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm working on a code piece which must load html file to my custom webview. I'm moving my file out of assets to a local folder. And from there I need to read the html to a webview. I need to move the file from assets folder so please don't suggest anything about assets.

This is how I move files:

```
    File f = new File(context.getFilesDir()+"/TMP/");
    try {

        String[] assets = {"editor.html", "normalize.css", "rich_editor.js", "style.css"};
        for(String a : assets)
        {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(a);

            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f + a);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to read it.

```
loadUrl("file://"+ new File(context.getFilesDir()+"/TMP/editor.html").getAbsolutePath());
```

I don't get an error or anything. But I do get a white screen and nothing else. I have thought that it might not be loading Javascript or CSS. But loading JS is enabled so it must work. Is any aditional editing required for html file due to moving it from one folder to another?

**Update:**
I know that the file is coppied successfully because I have checked it from inside the code and it's all good. I believe the problem is in the `WebView` method or linking.

I have also tried `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL()`. Both work the same. Blank screen

Comment: Add `fos.getFD().sync()` between `fos.write()` and `fos.close()`. Create your `TMP` directory, as you are not doing that here. Also, log your exceptions from your `catch` block.

Comment: @CommonsWare doesn't work. And I already have my folder created earlier. I will add a bit of info in the question